# Why does var type change when unpacking a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Consider this example:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = t
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, *b = t
>>> a, b
(1, [2, 3])
```

Why do I get a list instead of a tuple when unpacking a tuple with `a, *b = t` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), this is extended iterable unpacking. The type doesn't "change"; it is just defined that `*` unpacking will yield a list in all cases.

It was proposed for it to yield:

- A tuple instead of a list:

> Make the starred target a tuple instead of a list. This would be consistent with a function's `*args`, but make further processing of the result harder.

- The same type as the right-hand side:

> Try to give the starred target the same type as the source iterable, for example, `b` in `a, *b = 'hello'` would be assigned the string `'ello'`. This may seem nice, but is impossible to get right consistently with all iterables.

Ultimately, these proposals were rejected.

For some more insight, see [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007378.html) and [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007391.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information in this link https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/ but I think it's essentially because this is generic iterable unpacking so it converts things to a list first to handle for the generic case:

> Also, if the right-hand value is not a list, but an iterable, it has
>   to be converted to a list before being able to do slicing

I think tuple is a special case where the implementation could allow for it returned as a tuple, since tuples already allow slicing but it looks like the decision was made to implement the most generic version in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.0, the `*` operator was added to the multiple assignment syntax, allowing us to capture remaining items after an unpacking into a list. The `*` operator allows us to replace hard-coded slices near the ends of sequences.

Arccording your code:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = t
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, *b = t
>>> a, b
(1, [2, 3])
```

The same code:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = t
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a, *b = t[0], t[1:]
>>> a, b
(1, [2, 3])
```

Read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).